# Value to trigger custom message + checkbox to disable/enable element

Tags: jquery

Found a great snippet on here , so fiddled with it and it does pretty much exactly what I want it to do. But .. obviously we dont want to run "strings" in value box, as we are attaching this form element to database.

So here is the script:
http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/gwKfP/10/

Here is the code ( html )

```
<select id="duration">
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option value="$7.99">7 days</option>
 <option value="$3.99">3 days</option>
</select>
```

I would prefer to have this all triggered off something other than value.. not sure if thats dooable.

Also in our form we have a checkbox immediately before this select box. I really would like it so unchecked , disables the select until the checkbox is ticked. Also if checkbox is unticked is there a way of changing value of select to zero ( 0 )

We use jquery ( but as you may guess I dont get js ) lol

My actual code is :

```
<label class="s_radio"><input class="inline" type="checkbox" value="ctv"/> yes</label>
            <label class="s_radio">
                <select id="duration" class="inline" style="width: 100px;">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="$7.99">7 days</option>
                <option value="$3.99">3 days</option>
                </select>&nbsp; <span id="value" class="disabled" data-default="Please Choose"> Please Choose</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your document.ready function:

```
$('.s_radio input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $('#duration').attr('disabled', '');
    else
        $('#duration').val('').change().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: great thankyou, that disables checkbox ( if checked ) need it other way round. Thats part two of my issue solved thankyou

Comment: Edited. I don't understand your first problem. What would you like to use besides the values? Or why is it not appropriate to use the value?

Comment: Fyi, in recent jquery versions you can use `.prop('disabled', true_or_false)`

Comment: That was my first thought too, but .prop() does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: @adam updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/gwKfP/32/ its very hit and miss on the disable. You have to check and uncheck cpl of times until it disables. Perhaps I did it wrong. Also the issue with value , is just that we wish to use similar code to what I have posted for other form elements ( selects ) on the page, and even specifying id's as per fiddle, when you run multiple instances it goes pear shaped, because value is the handler

Comment: You really need to try to help yourself a little here. If you want the select to start disabled then you need to add that tag. I was simply showing you how you can toggle it from the checkbox.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are talking about with the select boxes going pear shaped? But here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/gwKfP/37/

Comment: I think the issue is we are triggering the disbale off label class s_radio. This class is used throughout the document